# Status Message during function call (WPF, Multithreadin)

Tags: wpf

I have one "CleanUp" button on my WPF UI.By clicking on this button, I"ll call some C++ wrapper function to do some calculation.The calculation will take some time.
What I want exactly:
1. During calculation, I want to show some message like "Clean-Up is going on" besides one node of TreeView (TreeView is present on same UI.

Any help would be appreciated........

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Just set a new background worker and set it's dowork event to your "wrapper function to do some calculation" ;-)

After that you can trigger the reportprogress event to set a new state or message while it's executing.

Comment: I think in WPF, we have some concept of Dispatcher object also.....it would be great if you can give me some URL for code example....Thanks

Comment: I used BackgroundWorker with WPF too. I don't know if there is a better way to do it ;-)

Comment: Anyway, you have an example for backgroundworker in my answer link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Here you have another example ;-) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S4